# Array of functions handling in C

Tags: c, arrays, function

I've declared an array of functions as:

```
void * (thread_fun[100])(void *);
```

But, compilation is terminated with error:

> error: declaration of ‘thread_fun’ as array of functions  void *
>   (thread_fun[])(void *);

What is wrong with my declaration. And, how it can be corrected.
I want to create an array of function in my program. Suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 8):

It's not possible to declare array of functions. You can only declare array of pointers to function:

```
void * (*thread_fun[100])(void *);
```

Answer (score 1):

As user *Zbynek Vyskovsky* noted, you can only have array of function pointers.

However, I would also recommend that you use `typedef` to make handling of function pointers easier:

```
typedef void* (*FunctionPtrType)(void*);  // Define type
FunctionPtrType thread_fun[100];          // Declare the array
```